# Case when expression in JPQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, spring-data

I am having problem when I implement 'CASE WHEN' condition with JPQL

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
</dependency>


select u 
  from user u
  where u.languageId = case
  when :userLanguageId is null then :managerLanguageID
  else :userLanguageId 
   end
```

I want to get data based on managerLanguageID if data corresponding userLanguageId is null. So the problem occurs when I use parameter with THEN keyword. but it works fine if I set the parameter manually like:

```
select u 
  from user u
  where u.languageId = case
  when :userLanguageId is null then 1
  else :userLanguageId 
   end
```

btw,.Here is the exception it throws:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ParameterNode cannot be cast to
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectExpression  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.(SimpleJpaQuery.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.fromQueryAnnotation(SimpleJpaQuery.java:132)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:114)

Comment: So "u.languageId= :userLanguageId is null" is supposed to be a boolean expression. Perhaps "u.languageId= :userLanguageId"? or "u.languageId is NULL"?

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems wrong for me:

```
select u 
from user u
where u.language_id = case
  when (u.languageId = :userLanguageId is null) then 1
  else :userLanguageId 
end
```

It should be:

```
select u 
from user u
where u.languageId = case
  when :userLanguageId is null then 1
  else :userLanguageId 
end
```

Because:

```
(1) u.languageId =  :userLanguageId is null 
(2) u.languageId = (:userLanguageId is null)
(3) <long> = <boolean>
```

Expression (1) is equivalent to (2), and type of (2) are those of (3): you are comparing a long to a boolean, and I don't think Hibernate will accept that.

And, since `coalesce` exists for that:

```
select u 
from user u
where u.language_id = coalesce(:userLanguageId, 1)
```

Comment: thanks for pointing my written mistake..But my point is to make use of passed variable in query with THEN keyword.. when I execute this query it throws exception:


select u 
from user u
where u.languageId = case
  when :userLanguageId is null then :managerLanguageId
  else :userLanguageId 
end

Comment: Then you should check the java type of `managerLanguageID` and `userLanguageId` which must match those of `u.languageId`. And use coalesce => `coalesce(:userLanguageId, :managerLanguageID)`.

Comment: Thanku so much for the reply.. I made my query with expecetd result with use of coalesce(:userLanguageId, :managerLanguageID)..

Comment: select u 
from user u
where u.language_id = coalesce(:userLanguageId, :managerLanguageID)

I WANTED WHEN RESULTS IS NULL WITH USERLANGUAGE THEN IT SHOULD FETCH RESULT WITH MANAGERLANGUAGE .. BUT IT IS NOT BEHAVING LIKE THIS.......................... :(

Comment: No need to use upper case... So in fact, you want something like `select from user where languageId = :userLanguageId` and if none found, `select from user where languageId = :managerLanguageId` ?

Comment: Then the question does not reflect your need or it's another question. Update it to reflect your real need and explains what is an User, what the first query should return (because it will returns more than one result), and so on.

Comment: I know it returns more than one result.. So bascially i want to fetch all the user records having userlanguage(let suppose 2 for all users.) and if user doest have language 2 then query needs to fetch records with managerLangaage(i.e 3).............. and this is what i wanted to achieve in my initial question

Comment: Then execute one query after the other ? One to fetch user given their language, and - if no result - another to fetch based managerLangaage.

Comment: There are some other condition which I need to met with this query. So I cant use that thing. The above query which I mentioned with my question works but only in my query editor it doest work with hibernate.. as it was bug with hibernate https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8124  so I am looking alternative for the same.

Comment: I fail to understand: are you OK that the coalesce thing and your case in the query are the same ? ie: if the provided userLanguageId is null, then use another. That the same as using coalesce(a,b) : if a is null, then it returns b. I find it easier to read, unless your case condition is much complex and coalesce can't do the work here.

Answer (score 1):

I got it.. I got the solution.The class cast exception that occured because CaseNode.getDataType requires a SelectExpression. So we need to explicitly cast the dynamic parameter(in integer or string whatever the datatype we need) what we send in our query.,........ 
CAST (:managerLanguageID as integer)

```
select u 
  from user u
  where u.languageId = case
  when :userLanguageId is null then CAST (:managerLanguageID as integer)
  else :userLanguageId 
   end
```